# Why is my non-greedy Pattern (.*?) greedy?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problems with a regexp pattern. I'm using the non-greedy **.*?** but it seems it is greedy, too? Can you help me, please?

**myString:**

```
myString = '{"testname":"mytest","type":{"aaa111":{"url":"http://www.test01.com"},"222bbb":{"url":"http://www.test02.com"},"ccc333":{"url":"http://www.test03.com"}}}';
```

**myPattern:**

```
/"(.*?)":{"url"/g
```

**The result:**

```
testname":"mytest","type":{"aaa111, http://www.test01.com"},"222bbb, http://www.test02.com"},"ccc333
```

**But the result "should" be:**

```
aaa111, 222bbb, ccc333
```

Comment: JS includes methods of parsing JSON natively.   Is there a reason you aren't using that?

Comment: `/ " ( [^"]+ ) ":\{"url" /gx`

Comment: @Daedalus Thank you, I had forgotten this function.

Comment: @Borodin thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is to make sure it doesn't match multiple `"` (double quotes)

```
"([^"]+?)":{"url
```

https://regex101.com/r/oU6eX4/1

Though I agree with the other comments that there are probably better solutions that don't involve regex.

Comment: thanks for the pattern. It helped me to understand my mistake :-)